# How (should) I use onBlur with onSubmit in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, user-experience

I have a form with multiple fields and want to avoid redoing validation/visual state updates on every keystroke (`onChange`). Don't want to delay validation until submit event either. `onBlur` seems appropriate middleground for this.

But what if a user clicks the submit button without interacting with the form at all? `onBlur` event would not be triggered, so validation/state updates would not occur. Does this mean I have to duplicate the validation/state update logic in my onBlurs and onSubmits? If so, how can I do this most optimally?

Technically, is it advisable to use `onBlur` with `onSubmit`?

Comment: Encapsulate your validation logic into a function or functions that can be called from anywhere